# Magento: API product.list error

Tags: magento

I am using Magento API to get list product. But it have error

```
$proxy = new SoapClient($this->_url);
$sessionId = $proxy->login($this->_user, $this->_api);
$filters = array(
    'sku' => array('like'=>'msj006%')
);
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list',$filters);
$resultEncode = json_encode($result);
```

But it giv error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean
What wrong here ?

Comment: Try without $filters..

Comment: How can i get list product with sku like msj006 if i remve $filters ?

Comment: You may need a nested array for your parameters: `$params = array($filters); $result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', $params);`. Because Magento is accepting more parameter than just filter (in this case `storeView`). This would look like `$storeView = 'default'; $params = [$filters, $storeView]; // ...`. BTW: This error occurs also, if you try to filter by an invalid attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have customized core part of magneto Or any extension which is customizing product model can create this issue. You can check your core code located at "app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php"

```
public function isAttributeStatic($attribute)
{
$attrInstance       = $this->getAttribute($attribute);
$attrBackendStatic  = $attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic();
return $attrInstance && $attrBackendStatic;
}
```